# Access Server in Local Environment

Tags: networking, server, internet

"Hello,

I recently purchased a static IP from my internet provider, PTCL, and successfully configured it with my server. Typically, when accessing our server, we use the static IP by making a request, and the router redirects it to the server. However, I am currently facing internet issues and wondering if it's possible to access the server locally using any internet connection or mobile data (LAN).

Since I have pending work, I need a solution to access the server urgently. Additionally, I am curious if it's feasible to configure multiple internet connections on my server. This way, if one network is not working, the server can automatically switch to another.

Here are some key details:

- Internet Provider: PTCL
- Server OS: Linux Ubuntu 22.04
- VM Manager: Hyper-V

I appreciate any guidance or solutions you can provide. Thank you."

Now,

I've decided to explore the option of configuring multiple gateways in Netplan to enhance the network redundancy on my server. However, I've encountered some difficulties in the configuration process.

Here's a brief overview of what I've attempted:

1. **Netplan Configuration:**

   - I've edited the Netplan YAML file to include multiple gateways.
   - Example snippet:

     ```yaml
     network:
       version: 2
       renderer: networkd
       ethernets:
         enp0s1:
           addresses: [192.168.1.2/24]
           gateway4: 192.168.1.1
           nameservers:
             addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
         enp0s2:
           addresses: [192.168.2.2/24]
           gateway4: 192.168.2.1
           nameservers:
             addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
     ```
2. **Issue Faced:**

   - Despite this configuration, it seems that only one gateway is being used, and there's no automatic failover to the second gateway if the first one is down.
3. **Request for Assistance:**

   - Could you provide insights into the correct Netplan configuration for multiple gateways and how to achieve automatic failover?

Comment: If you're on the same local network as the server, then you can connect normally using the local IP address. If you would configure another internet connection, then you would need to configure port forwarding (or routing) to work with the new connection also. However, your question does not contain enough detailed information to say specifically.

Comment: In any case, this is a network configuration question, and not directly an Ubuntu question.

Comment: Hi Artur Meinild,

Thank you for your previous response. I've decided to explore the option of configuring multiple gateways in Netplan to enhance the network redundancy on my server. However, I've encountered some difficulties in the configuration process.
I have edit my question..

Comment: Please have a look [here](https://netplan.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/#how-to-use-multiple-addresses-with-multiple-gateways). Also not that the `gateway4` property is no longer used, and it's now done with `routes` instead.